# Using std_logic_vector with logical operators

Tags: vhdl

I'm trying to use logical operators on an `std_logic_vector` signal and an `std_logic` signal, and get an output of either logic 1 (high) or logic 0 (low) and place it in `room1` signal

```
entity sample is
   port(
       source: in std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
       sw1: in std_logic;
       sw2: in std_logic;
       room1: out std_logic;
       room2: out std_logic
  );
end entity;

architecture behv of sample is
begin
  process (source, sw1, sw2)
  begin
    room1 <= (source="01" and sw1);
  wait for 10 ns;

end behv;
```

However, I'm getting errors. I'm new to vhdl, how is this done? Thank you!

Comment: Show the complete error messages. Note there is no end for the process statement. Also a process can't contdain explicit wait statements and also have a process sensitivity list.

Comment: What type does the expression `source="01"` return?   Here that is important.    If you are allowed to use VHDL-2008 and if for synthesis, you synthesis tool allows you to use it you might look at the `?=` operator.   Otherwise you will either need an if statement or a conditional assignment to handle this properly.

Comment: You need to post the errors! However, I can see another one: `source` is 3 bits wide; you cannot compare that to a 2-bit wide _literal_ `"01"`. What are you expecting to happen to bit 2? (A `std_logic_vector` is not a number, it's just an arbitrary collection of `std_logic` bits.)